# Using dplyr to store the output of regression

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

```
df.h <- data.frame( 
                hour = factor(rep(1:24, each = 21)),
                price = runif(504, min = -10, max = 125),
                wind = runif(504, min = 0, max = 2500),
                temp = runif(504, min = - 10, max = 25))
```

If I want to do a linear regression of price against wind and price against temp, I could do this:

```
df.h %>% group_by(hour) %>% do(mod1 = lm(price ~ wind , data = .), 
                                   mod2 = lm(price ~ temp, data = .))
```

Howver, what I want to is to extract the residuals of mod1 and mod2 and store the residuls as two additional 
columns

```
df.h %>% group_by(hour) %>% 
         do(mod1 = lm(price ~ wind , data = .), 
            mod2 = lm(price ~ temp, data = .)) %>%
         mutate(mod1.resid = resid(mod1),
                mod2.resid = resid(mod2))
```

However, this is not working. Could you help me please.

Comment: You might be interested in the [broom](http://varianceexplained.org/r/broom-intro/) package, see the example right *before* the "Using tidiers for visualization with ggplot2" headline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mod <- df.h %>% group_by(hour) %>% do(mod1 = resid(lm(price ~ wind , data = .)), 
                           mod2 = resid(lm(price ~ temp, data = .))) 

df.h <- df.h %>% 
     mutate(res1 = unlist(mod$mod1),
     res2 = unlist(mod$mod2))
```

Probably there's an even more compact solution, that I'm trying to figure out.